# Refreshing every page on my website apart from home page returns a 404 not found error; deployed with vercel

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, vite, vercel

I built a website with react and vite and used `react-router` for routing, which I then deployed with vercel.
The website works fine but every time I refresh any page but the landing/home page, it directs me to a not found 404 error message. The links on the website work fine so you can navigate to every page but the issue only arises when I refresh a page (except home page).

Here is my App.jsx page if relevant:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Themes from './components/Themes';
import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import About from './pages/about/About';
import Portfolio from './pages/portfolio/Portfolio';
import Contact from './pages/contact/Contact';
import CTA from './components/CTA';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Themes />
      <CTA />
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/portfolio' element={<Portfolio />} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think you need to pass exact prop to all your Route

Comment: i thought the best way was like how I did? can you please show me your way

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: latest for everything

Comment: This is a server/hosting issue, not something you solve in the frontend code. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#vercel) for Vercel to see what you need to setup/configure. The basic gist is that you need to return the root index.html file for ***all*** page requests into the app. How this is done depends on the server/hosting environment.

Comment: @Santa is that possible for you to add a https://stackblitz.com/ reproducer for me to check the issue?